# Unable to Download the multiple csv file at once and how to zip files in one with same code i have written

Tags: python, csv, download, zip

I have a code which is written in python flask which will read the data from csv file and write to the csv file all the operation has been done from UI so from Ui i will select the file from system and when click on Generate data it will generate the and dump the newly generated data to the new csv file and after the operation is done the csv file will downloaded automatically to the local.
**For download single file I have written a code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
do all operation here....
..........................
at last come with Generated data and store in dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(final_Array) # "final_Array" contains the data

now performing download operation:
resp = make_response(data .to_csv(index=False,))
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=OutputData.csv"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```

this looks like this shown in the picture:
[image]
You can see in down the csv file is downloaded the name of "outputData.csv" so **same way i want to download the multiple file in the browser but i'm not getting how to do it.** 
now i have three file which is looks like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(final_Array)
data1=result.drop(result.iloc[:,64:], axis=1)
data1.to_csv("C:\\Users\\rahul\\Desktop\\newCSVFile\\parts.csv",index=False)
data2=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:64], axis=1)
data2=data2.drop(data2.iloc[:,19:],axis=1)
data2.to_csv("C:\\Users\\rahul\\Desktop\\newCSVFile\\Skills.csv",index=False)
data3=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:75], axis=1)
data3.to_csv("C:\\Users\\rahul\\Desktop\\newCSVFile\\predict.csv",index=False)
return "done"
```

**I have written a code to download multiple file at once :**

```
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('SrID')))
result = data.reindex(columns= cols)
data1=result.drop(result.iloc[:,64:], axis=1)
resp1 = make_response(data1.to_csv(index=False,))
resp1.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=parts.csv"
resp1.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"

data2=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:64], axis=1)
data2=data2.drop(data2.iloc[:,19:],axis=1)
resp2 = make_response(data2.to_csv(index=False,))
resp2.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=Skills.csv"
resp2.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"

data3=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:75], axis=1)
resp3 = make_response(data3.to_csv(index=False,))
resp3.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=predict.csv"
resp3.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return (resp1, resp2, resp3)
```

**This is not working for all its works when i will return one response at a time i want to download all files at once**....please help me get that way ...thnx in advance

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky please look my question once you have answered the similar kind of question so you can suggest me correct way..thnx

Comment: @davidism please suggest me the correct way how to do this cause you already answer one similar question...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ sir please help me with this question as you have answered in the similar kind of question so i think this will be easy suggestion for you..thnx

Comment: @jezrael please can you suggest me the correct way..any help will be appreciable...thnx

Comment: @Dan Loewenherz please can you suggest me how to use my code for the zip file i have three files which want to zip into single file and download it to the browser..any help will be appreciable..thnxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the multiple files and then download it...this way:

```
data1=result.drop(result.iloc[:,64:], axis=1)
# data1=data1.to_csv("parts.csv") 

data2=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:64], axis=1)
data2=data2.drop(data2.iloc[:,19:],axis=1)
# data2 = data2.to_csv("Skills.csv")

data3=result.drop(result.iloc[:,8:75], axis=1)
# data3 = data3.to_csv("predict.csv")

file_List = [data1, data2, data3]
name_list = ['parts.csv', 'skills.csv','predict.csv']

def zipFiles(file_List):
    outfile = io.BytesIO() 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, 'w') as zf:
        for name, data in zip(name_list, file_List):
           zf.writestr(name, data.to_csv())
    return outfile.getvalue()
zipped_file = zipFiles(file_List)
response = make_response(zipped_file)
response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=anyFileName.zip"
return response
```

This will zip the all 3 files in one and download as single file